# I need more frequent updates of my Facebook calender on my phone than Google Calender offers

Tags: calendar, facebook, google-calendar

There seems to be a limit to how often Google Calender updates subscribed calenders, something like once per day. I need a more frequent update than that, once an hour or so, because my Facebook calender, which I subscribe to in Google calender and from there sync to my Android phone, often changes several times a day.

On my Mac, this is not an issue because I can set the calender to update every 15 minutes.

**How can I achieve more frequent updates of a subscribed calender on an Android phone while I also display my other calenders in the same view?** (That is, if the solution is some other calender service, app or whatever, it has to be able to display my other calenders similar to how it works in the stock calender app)

Comment: So you have set-up Google to pull changes from your Facebook calendar or is the Facebook calendar directly set-up on your Android phone using the Facebook account?

Comment: Google pulls it from Facebook. Didn't know you can add the Facebook calender directly on the phone, can you? How?

Comment: The frequency Google pulls external calendars is not up to the user to decide. That seems to be done by some magic algorithm on Google side. So directly syncing the Facebook calendar would be a preferred solution as you then have the power to change the sync frequency.

Comment: @Robert That was kind of the solution I was looking for but since it is OT to ask directly for software recommendations I had to put it like I did.

Comment: From what I read the Facebook app supports adding events into an Android calendar. Not sure if this is a real sync. Alternatively calendars are usually exported in iCal format and there are apps that can sync local calendar with an iCal URL.

Comment: Yes, but that is a manual process. On my iOS-devices and desktop computers, since they sync directly and on my command, keeping the Facebook calender up to date works fine. The problem with Android stock calender is that they take the detour via Google Calender for their syncing.